# Do not scale ScrollViewer children, that are inside Canvas

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have a ScrollViewer which has a Canvas inside it. To make this construction support panning, I'm setting MinZoomFactor and MaxZoomFactor to 4.

Is it possible to **NOT** apply scale on elements that are added later at runtime to the canvas? How can I achieve it? LayoutTransform is not available in WinRT, and I didn't manage to apply RenderTransform.Inverse to canvas child elements to compensate scale.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no way to allow the ScrollViewer to scroll / zoom some of its contents but not others. If you don't want the Canvas to scroll / zoom at all then you can place it on top of rather than in the ScrollViewer.

If you want to allow it to scroll but not to zoom then you can try applying an inverse [ScaleTransform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.media.scaletransform.aspx) to it by setting the ScaleX and ScaleY values to 1 / ScrollViewer.[ZoomFactor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.zoomfactor.aspx) .